# validation and submit form in db in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to submit data into db when the user fills a form. But it is behaving strangely.

This is my contoller function:

```
      namespace App\Http\Controllers\PrivatePages;
      use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
      use App\Http\Requests\Request\CreateProductRequest;
      /*use App\Productuse Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;*/
      use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
      use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
      use App\Http\FormRequests;


    public function UpdateAdminProfile(CreateProductRequest $request){
    Product::StoreProductDetails($request);
  }
```

This is my model function which defines the funtion:

```
   namespace App;

   use App\Http\Requests\CreateProductRequest;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
   use App\Http\Controllers\PrivatePages;



  use  Illuminate\Http\Request;

public static function StoreProductDetails(CreateProductRequest $request)
{

        $saveproduct = new Product();
        $saveproduct->name = $request->get('name');
    $saveproduct->description = $request->get('description');
    $saveproduct->save();

}
```

this is my request file:

```
<?php
     namespace App\Http\Requests\Request;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
    class CreateProductRequest extends FormRequest
 {
 /**
  * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{

    return [

        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'contactinfo'=> 'required',

    ];

}



   public function messages()
   {
      return[
        'name.required' => 'Enter Name',
        'description.required' => 'Enter description',
        'contact.required' => 'Enter contact info',

    ];
    }
  }
```

my form

```
   @if (Session::has('success'))
   <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="font-size: 18px;">
    <strong>Success: </strong>

    {{ Session::get('success') }}
 </div>
  @endif

       <form id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ 
      route('updateadminprofile')}}"enctype="multipart/form-data" >



      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="userName"> Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" 
      placeholder="name}"  value="name" />
     </div>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="userName"> Description</label>
   <div class="col-sm-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" 
   name="description" placeholder="Description}"  value="description" />
  </div>
  </div>
     <button  style="margin-left: 30%" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
       name="signup" value="sumbmit" >Save</button>
```

It is not giving error

```
 jsut refreshes the page and no record is saving in db
```

Why is it throwing an error as every thing seems good? Now it just Refreshes the page. not even going to route specified in action of form

Comment: What if you `dd($request);`?

Comment: on dd it gives me this line "CreateProductRequest {#177}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change Your **CreateProductRequest** to the following by extending **FormRequest** not **Request**

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'contactinfo'=> 'required',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'name.required' => 'Enter Name',
        'description.required' => 'Enter description',
        'contact.required' => 'Enter contact info',
    ];
}
}
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: have you checked your database record??

Comment: can you update your modified code?? and make sure your model and db table are correctly connected and working.

Comment: it should work now, what's your problem exactly after updating??

Comment: As per above code. when i try to submit form using button present in my form record in not saving in db. infact it is now not even going to route specified in the action of form. On button click of submit browser just refreshes and stays on the same form.

Comment: in your rules function before retrun try to dd($request->all()) or dd(Input::all())

Comment: its not going in the request file as i did dd in rules funtion. its not even going to function specified in controller

Comment: You have a contactInfo in your rule which is required but you are not passing as form field, possibly it is causing you the problem

Comment: no its not causing the problem as i have tried with out contact info. i have just created the new laravel project and try to submit form after validation. i have no login no registeration form. i just want to submit form in db. It is saving record in db when i remove Request file and give hard coded values to fields in controller funtion.

Comment: remove line  'contactinfo'=> 'required', from rule function and try again

Comment: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Product::StoreProductDetails() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\CreateProductRequest, instance of App\Http\Requests\Request\CreateProductRequest

Comment: @raja It is unfair why not my answer was accepted. As you check your initial question, I am solved your other problems regarding your question, then you edited your question with my answers and accepted others answer, which looks like same as my more detailed answer.

Comment: sorry i ignored by mistake.. main purpose is to solve question and share knowledge and i think here you, me and other fellow achieved this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
public static function StoreProductDetails(CreateProductRequest $request)
{
    $saveproduct = new Product();
    $saveproduct->name = $request->get('name');
    $saveproduct->description = $request->get('description');
    $saveproduct->save();
}
```

And change your `CreateProductRequest.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateProductRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'contactinfo'=> 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'Enter Name',
            'description.required' => 'Enter description',
            'contact.required' => 'Enter contact info',
        ];
    }
}
```

Edited: you can check errors in view

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159927/discussion-on-answer-by-jeugen-validation-and-submit-form-in-db-in-laravel).